# Cross-domain $http request AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, http, cross-domain

I have simple website I'm building with AngularJS which calls an API for json data.

However I am getting Cross domain origin problem is there anyway around this to allow for cross domain requests?

Error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?country=uk&pretty=1&action=search_listings&place_name=soho&encoding=json&listing_type=rent. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:// localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

```
  searchByPlaceName: function() { 
        var url = baseurl+'country=uk&pretty=1&action=search_listings&place_name=london'+encoding+type;
         return $http.get(url);
    }
```

Comment: It is up to api.nestoria.co.uk to allow CORS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that `api.nestoria.co.uk` does not allow CORS.  It has to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header itself -- you have no direct control over that.

However, you can use JSONP.  That site allows it via the `callback` query parameter.

```
$http.jsonp(baseurl+'country=uk&pretty=1&action=search_listings&place_name=london'
    +encoding+type + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
```

Comment: you need to supply a callback function to jsonp. $http.jsonp(url+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(data) { console.log(data); });

Comment: @huocp, your comment makes sense... However, I'm still getting the error Tom mentioned "Uncaught SyntaxError"

Comment: @Tom change the API response format to JSONP as well. :)

Comment: @Explosion Pills If i used JSONP the response is not coming as JSON format . it's in the form js file in response

Answer (score 2):

Install Fiddler. Add a custom rule to it:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session)
{
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

This would allow you to make cross domain requests from localhost. If the API is HTTPS make sure you enable 'decrypt HTTPS traffic' in fiddler.

[Reference](http://blog.caplin.com/2010/03/19/using-fiddler-to-help-develop-cross-domain-capable-javascript-web-applications/)

-------------------- UPDATE

The response you are getting is JSON. Specifying JSONP as datatype would not work. When you do specify JSONP the return should be a function not JSON object.

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)