# $http get returns not found,while the direct request works good

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to use one webAPI coded in ASP.net but when I try to get data from that API using angular $http.get at the browser console I get **GET <--URL--> Not found** When I try to make requests to the same URL directly it works fine and returns data to me. I tried to add .json mimetype at Web.config in the ASP project but still same result.

The working url is: https://adaba.azurewebsites.net/api/flights/searchairports?name=london - note that it's a GET request with a **required parameter** so you need to pass a parameter to get something.

Here you can execute directly the api request from this Codepen: http://codepen.io/albpower/pen/mVgyNP

JS file:

```
var app = angular.module("APP",[]);

app.controller("appCtrl",function($http,$scope){
  $scope.calculate = function(){
    $http.get('http://adaba.azurewebsites.net/api/flights/searchairports',{
      name: $scope.input
    }).then(function (resp) {
     console.log(resp);
      $scope.response = resp;
  });
  }
})
```

HTML file:

```
<div ng-app="APP" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <input type="text" placeholder="amount" ng-model="input"><br><br>

  <button ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button>

  <pre>
  {{response | json}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: You have [Same Origin Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489373/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-for-an-outside-domain) issue

Comment: it can be a cors issue, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546177/cross-domain-http-request-angularjs

Comment: Not a CORS issue: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in response header.

Comment: If your callback is not working then try with `$q` to resolve response

Comment: sure it is not http://adaba.azurewebsites.net/api/flights/searchairport without at the end?

Comment: @JohannesJander the URL works that without 's' at the end is returning wrong data, The working url is: http://adaba.azurewebsites.net/api/flights/searchairports?name=london
it's GET request with required parameter so you need to pass a parameter to get something

Comment: For clarification, I edited in your comment from below about the required parameter and the sample URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is:

- you are not setting the parameters for the request correctly, you need to do this with the `params` property

The code should be:

```
 $http.get('https://adaba.azurewebsites.net/api/flights/searchairports',{
      params: {name: $scope.input}
 }).then(function (resp) {
```

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMGpqX

Oh, and please use `https://`

Comment: the URL works that without 's' at the end is returning wrong data, The working url is: http://adaba.azurewebsites.net/api/flights/searchairports?name=london it's GET request with required parameter so you need to pass a parameter to get something 

PS: the problem is solved by putting params: before the name: input and it  works, I didn't know that was required anyway thanks for your help and update your answer with the 's' at the url so I can choose your answer 

PPS: updated codepen: http://codepen.io/albpower/pen/mVgyNP